# Downloading a file from another computer in same network C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip, lan

I got 3 computers in local network and I need a program in C# that

1. Read the IP address of computer you want to connect from a txt file
2. Read the destination of the file you want to get
3. Download a file from the computer

I don't have any specific protocols or permissions
Sorry that the question is so broad and generic

Comment: You mean like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-download-files-with-ftp

Comment: Yeah something like this thanks ! It will help a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FTPWebRequest class which is part of the .net framework located here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try code mentioned in below article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-download-files-with-ftp